# joomla loadformdata

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

how to show data from 3 tables in one view, because using JTable i can show data only bind to that JTable, please help me with this one.

my code so far(not working) in models:

```
public function getEntireProject(){
    $item_id = $this->getItem()->id;

    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('*');
    $query->from('#__project_part_1 AS a');
    $query->leftJoin('#__project_part_2 AS u ON a.uuid = u.uuid');
    $query->leftJoin('#__project_part_3 AS y ON a.uuid = y.uuid');
    $query->where('a.id = '. (int) $item_id);
    $db->setQuery($query);
    return $db->loadResult();
}

protected function loadFormData()
{
    // Check the session for previously entered form data.
    $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_web_projects.edit.webproject.data', array());

    if (empty($data)) {
        $data = $this->getEntireProject();
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: What are you getting in $data?

Comment: in $data there is resault from query getEntireProject

Comment: Than it should work as Dasun suggested use  loadAssocList() instead of loadResult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to overwrite getItem function.This will also be helpful if you are calling get('Item') in view. -

```
public function getItem($pk = null){
    if ($item = parent::getItem($pk)) {
        $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('*');
        $query->from('#__project_part_1 AS a');
        $query->leftJoin('#__project_part_2 AS u ON a.uuid = u.uuid');
        $query->leftJoin('#__project_part_3 AS y ON a.uuid = y.uuid');
        $query->where('a.id = '. (int) $item->id);
        $db->setQuery($query);          
        $item =  $db->loadAssoc();
    }   
    return $item;
}

protected function loadFormData()
{
    // Check the session for previously entered form data.
    $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_web_projects.edit.webproject.data', array());

    if (empty($data)) {
    $data = $this->getItem();
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: ok i got that data i just used loadAssoc() and that solver the issue

Answer (score 1):

For Multi-Row Results use loadRowList(), loadAssocList(), loadAssocList($key), loadObjectList(), loadObjectList('key'). $db->loadResult() only load one result. ***[Read more](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase)***.

If I understand your question right this should fix your problem. If you not please ask.

Comment: i have 3 table for example a, b, c and in admin view i have 1 view that show data from table a, and i want to show data from table a, b, c but i don't know how to do that

Comment: works fine for me. can you be more specific what's the issue?