# Insert DB Value into Form Field

Tags: php, html, xml, joomla, joomla3.0

**The Question:** How do I insert values from a database table (#__mytable) into form text fields (`motitle` and `modescription`) which have been rendered from an XML file within the Joomla 3.0 platform?

-

I've been trying for days to solve this "easy" Joomla! based undocumented challenge.
I have followed [Joomla!'s guide for Developing an MVC](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Introduction), read most of their out-of-date documentation and torn apart the `com_content` component but have still no idea how to populate my fields.

I've been playing with `$this->form->bind($this->item);`.

Below I have included some of my code to show the structure I am using.  Please feel free to point out any issues you spot along the way.

**Models\Forms\item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
    <fields name="groupOPTIONS">
        <fieldset name="Options">
            <field
                type="text"
                name="motitle"
                id="motitle"
                label="Title"
                description="MY TEXT FIELD DESCRIPTION"
                maxLength="255" />
            <field
                type="textarea"
                name="modescription"
                id="modescription"
                label="Description"
                description="MY TEXT FIELD DESCRIPTION"
                rows="15"
                cols="5"
                maxLength="255" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</form>
```

**Models\item.php**

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.modelitem');
class MagicObjectsModelItem extends JModelForm {

public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true) {
    // Get the form 'items'
    $form = $this->loadForm('com_magicobjects.item', 'item',
        array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));

if (empty($form)) {
    return false;
}

            return $form;
}

protected function loadFormData() {
    // Check the session for previously entered form data.
    $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_magicobjects.item.edit.data', array());

    if (empty($data)) {
            $data = $this->getDBItem(1);
    }

    return $data;
}

public function getDBItem($pk) {
    //Obtain JDatabase static connection
    $oDb = JFactory::getDbo();
    $oQuery = $oDb->getQuery(true);
    $sValueToMatch = $pk;
    $oQuery
        ->select(array('mid', 'name', 'keyword', 'description'))
        ->from('#__mytable')
        ->where('mid = "' . $sValueToMatch . '"')
        ->order('mid ASC');

    $oDb->setQuery($oQuery);
    return $oDb->loadObjectList();
}
```

**views\item\view.html.php**

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

function display($tpl = null) {

    // Initialise variables.
    $this->form = $this->get('Form');
    $this->item = $this->get('Item');

//Display the view
    parent::display($tpl);
}
```

**Views\item\tmpl\default.php**

```
foreach ($this->form->getFieldset('Options') as $field) {
    echo $field->label;
    echo $field->input;
}
```

By performing a print_r() on item I can see I have the data, but I need to insert the data into the fields shown.

[image: Data Available in Array but not within fields]

Comment: did you use `loadFormData` function in to your model?

Comment: @Tornado Thanks, I have added loadFormData to my model again, I removed it before as it didn't seem to do much.  I have also included it in my code samples above (along with the db fetch function).

Comment: @Tornado - No not currently.  I have the data returned when calling $this->item = $this->get('Item'); but the data is not present in the form fields.  See image I have attached to my OP.  How to I insert the values into the fields?

Comment: I have since tried renaming the fieldnames to match the db table column names, but obviously this isn't enough alone, is there a binding function or something similar that I should be using?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In case this it's still a problem because the form definition is defining a `<fields />` group.

This mean that the form fields will be output as follows:

```
input type="text" name="[groupOPTIONS][motitle]"
```

*based on the example you give above*. If you remove the fields grouping it will probably work. It's annoying though as certain JForm methods only work on groups...

You would probably need to change the way in which the data was being passed into the form if you wanted to keep the fields grouping (e.g. by overloading getItem).

Hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla 3, the `JForm::bind()` method appears to accept either an object or associative array as a parameter. All of the object/array fields are then stored in a protected `JRegistry` type data member called `JForm::$data`.

When you're trying to display a form field (by calling `JForm::getInput()`), the call stack is as follows

```
JForm::getInput() -> JForm::getField() -> JForm::loadField() -> JForm::getValue()
```

`JForm::getValue()` returns a value from the (aforementioned `JRegistry`) `JForm::$data` data member. The `JForm::loadField()` method also passes the default value (defined by the form) to the `JForm::getValue()` method in case a value in the `JForm::$data` variable doesn't exist.

In terms of doing this inside a model, you might want to generate a object or assoc array from a database query or table (ensuring that the field names correspond with the field names defined in the form xml) and then pass it to `JForm::bind()` as a parameter. However, if you are using `JModelForm`, I think you should only override `JModelForm::loadFormData()` to pass the object/assoc array to the loaded form.

See : `libraries/joomla/form/form.php`

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$oDb->loadObjectList();` use `$oDb->loadAssoc();` in your `getDBItem()` function.

Check this - http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/1.5

Check this also - [joomla loadformdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928475/joomla-loadformdata/12928984#12928984)

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, however unfortunately this does not resolve the my issue of not getting values into the field.  I have now removed the function getDBItems() and created an extended JTable class within the folder Tables.

Comment: @MatthewBaker:I have updated the answer you can try if you like.:)

Comment: Thanks Irfan.  It doesn't appear to resolve the problem.  I am retrieving the data OK, it's just the assigning to the textbox that is causing the issue.